# How to check if JPlayer is playing

Tags: jquery, jplayer

How I can use Jquery to check if JPlayer is playing? I tried searching but it seems like all previous answers are already outdated as it doesn't work anymore with the latest version.

```
If(Jplayer is playing) {
    $("#id").css("display", "block");
} 
else {
    $("#id").css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('.jp-play').click(function() {
  if($("#jquery_jplayer_1").data().jPlayer.status.paused === false){
                        $("p").show();
                    }
                    else{
                        $("p").hide();
                    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function () {
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            title: "Bubble",
                            m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3",
                            oga: "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
                        }).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/dist/jplayer",
                    supplied: "mp3, oga",
                    wmode: "window",
                    useStateClassSkin: true,
                    autoBlur: false,
                    smoothPlayBar: true,
                    keyEnabled: true,
                    remainingDuration: true,
                    toggleDuration: true
                });

                setTimeout(function(){
                    if($("#jquery_jplayer_1").data().jPlayer.status.paused === false){
                        $("p").hide();
                    }
                    else{
                        $("p").show();
                    }
                }, 500);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried all 3 of them and nothing seems to be working. Here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g2p9sLv8/22/

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng , i have Updated your Fiddle. You might like the trick i have used.   Let me know.

Comment: Hi, can you link it to me? I can't seem to find the updated one. Thanks

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng  , Ooppss  i did change your fiddle but i dnt know hy it was not a updated.  anyways,  check this [https://jsfiddle.net/akffxhdb/](https://jsfiddle.net/akffxhdb/)

Comment: Thanks I see the updated code now. I'm just wondering if it's possible to toggle the message like if I click pause it will show and if i click play the message will hide.

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng , i have updated my answer and fiddle as well.. please check it

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng , Glad to help . . . . :-)